# Override active object for "bpy.ops.modifier_remove" then display in UI

Tags: python, scripting

i've been running into some problem when experimenting with override. 
i never got it working, am i doing something wrong ? [I'm following the doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html) so i don't understand

```
override = bpy.context.copy()
override['active_object'] =  bpy.data.objects['Terrain']
bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(override,modifier='Array')
```

```
override = {'window':win,
            'screen':scr,
            'area'  :areas3d[0],
            'region':region[0],
            'scene' :bpy.context.scene,
            'active_object': bpy.data.objects['Terrain']
            }
bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(override,modifier='Array')
```

Both methods don't work for me
after getting this working, the logical next step is displaying an override arg in the UI ? 
as the override is don't have any args i can base my code on (see below)

```
t = layout.operator("object.modifier_remove", text="remove")
t.modifier = 'Array'
??? t.override = ???
```

until now i always did some 'manual' override. like this below but it's kind of amateurish, (is it? )
see below

```
def override_modifier_remove(obj,mod_name):
    #messy override
    Active = bpy.context.object
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier=mod_name)

    #restore messy override
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = Active
    return
```

Bests

Comment: maybe it's not working because i'm executing this from the text editor?

Comment: nope, even with an operator execute from 3D view, it's not working

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts.

Comment: If it works without passing a custom context, don't create a custom context. The poll function that is called for the operator is `edit_modifier_poll` which calls `edit_modifier_poll_generic` ([object_modifier.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/object/object_modifier.c)). Setting the active object should be all that you need to do.

Comment: Depending on whether you've created the object in your script or if that is a user created object, you may also need to make sure that the object isn't linked, having a library override or that it's currently in edit mode.